# login en php y mysql

Tags: php

Estoy realizando un proyecto de login para una pagina web, estoy comparando la contraseña junto con el correo que tengo en la base de datos y no funciona siempre me dice que el correo o contraseña son incorrectas aunque sean correctas, ya imprimí mi consulta y efectivamente si lo envía bien, no se que este sucediendo.
Adjunto correo y foto de mi base de datos :(

```
 <?php
    session_start();

    include 'conexionCom.php';
    if(isset($_POST['iniciar'])){
     
    $correo = $_POST['correo'];
    $contraseña = $_POST['contraseña'];
    $contraseña = hash('sha512',$contraseña);

    $consulta="SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE 
    correo = '$correo' AND contraseña ='$contraseña'";
    
    $ejecutar =mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta );
    
    if(!empty($ejecutar) AND mysqli_num_rows($ejecutar) > 0){
        $_SESSION['usuario']=$correo;
        header("location:http://localhost/kslk/ksll/index.php");
        exit;
    }else{
        echo '
        <script>
        alert("Usuario o contraseña incorrecta");
        window.location = "http://localhost/kslk/ksll/login.html";
        </script>';
        exit;
    } 
}
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es incorrecto que hagas un hash de la contraseña que manda el usuario de nuevo (*ese nuevo hash no va a coincidir con el ya existente*), seguramente por eso no funciona, debes emplear el uso de la función `password_verify`

Comment: Agrega el código _como texto, con formato_. Lee [ask].

Comment: Si vas a hacer un **hash** de la contraseña entonces usa `password_verify` a la hora de comparar la contraseña del usuario con la de la base de datos